# ARM Template (InvalidTemplate) Deployment template validation failed

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a keyvault using ARM Templates. The template I am using as base is located at [azuredeploy.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/modules/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/1.0), I am not providing parameters for the creation, my intention is to use the default values that are available at the template just to start.
**Parameters file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":
  {
  }
}
```

> **(InvalidTemplate)** Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters '$schema, contentVersion, parameters' in the
> parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original
> template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The
> only supported parameters for this template are 'vaultName, location,
> enabledForDeployment, enabledForDiskEncryption,
> enabledForTemplateDeployment, enablePurgeProtection,
> enableRbacAuthorization, enableSoftDelete, softDeleteRetentionInDays,
> tenantId, networkRuleBypassOptions, NetworkRuleAction, ipRules,
> accessPolicies, virtualNetworkRules, skuName, tags'. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.
> **#Code:** InvalidTemplate
> **#Message:** Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters '$schema, contentVersion, parameters' in the parameters
> file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and
> can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported
> parameters for this template are 'vaultName, location,
> enabledForDeployment, enabledForDiskEncryption,
> enabledForTemplateDeployment, enablePurgeProtection,
> enableRbacAuthorization, enableSoftDelete, softDeleteRetentionInDays,
> tenantId, networkRuleBypassOptions, NetworkRuleAction, ipRules,
> accessPolicies, virtualNetworkRules, skuName, tags'. Please see
> https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.
> **Additional Information:Type:** TemplateViolation
> **Info:** {
> "lineNumber": 0,
> "linePosition": 0,
> "path": ""
> }

I also tried providing one or two parameters, but the error is still the same (Ex: If I provide the vaultName and/or location, those parameters doesn't disappear from the error message).
Based on the error message, the issue is at the parameters file, but I am not able to identify what is wrong. Do you have any clue where the error can be?

I am trying to deploy it with PowerShell (New-AzDeployment) and with python

**Python Code:

```
import os
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import DeploymentMode
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import Deployment
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import DeploymentProperties
from miscellaneous.logger import Logger
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import get_cloud_from_metadata_endpoint
from uuid6 import uuid7
class AzureConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, subscriptionId, resourceGroup):
        self.logger = Logger("Azure Connection")
        self.logger.info("Retrieving the list of available endpoint")
        endpoints = get_cloud_from_metadata_endpoint(os.environ.get("ARM_ENDPOINT"))
        self.subscriptionId = subscriptionId
        self.resourceGroup = resourceGroup
        self.credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
        self.logger.info("Creating a client for deploying resources on subscription {}".format(self.subscriptionId))
        self.client = ResourceManagementClient(self.credentials, self.subscriptionId,
            base_url=endpoints.endpoints.resource_manager)
        self.logger.success("Client was successfully created")
    def deploy(self, template):
        resources = ""
        for resource in template.get("resources"):
            resources += "\n\t {}".format(resource.get("type"))
        self.logger.info("The following resources: {}\nwill be deployed".format(resources))
        deploymentProperties = DeploymentProperties(
            mode=DeploymentMode.incremental,
            template=template
        )
        self.logger.info("Attempting deploy operation")
        try:
            deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
                self.resourceGroup,
                uuid7(),
                Deployment(properties=deploymentProperties)
            )
        except:
            self.logger.error("The resources could not be deployed");
        self.logger.success("Resources were successfully deployed")
    def deployWithParameters(self, template, parameters):
        resources = ""
        for resource in template.get("resources"):
            resources += "\n\t {}".format(resource.get("type"))
        self.logger.info("The following resources: {}\nwill be deployed".format(resources))
        parameters = {k: {"value": v} for k, v in parameters.items()}
        deploymentProperties = DeploymentProperties(
            mode=DeploymentMode.incremental,
            template=template,
            parameters=parameters
        )
        self.logger.info("Attempting deploy operation")
        deployment_async_operation = self.client.deployments.begin_create_or_update(
            self.resourceGroup,
            uuid7(),
            Deployment(properties=deploymentProperties)
        )

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
azureConnection = AzureConnection(os.environ.get("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"), os.environ.get("AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP"))
with open((os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates", <fileName>), "r") as file:
  template = json.load(file)
with open((os.path.dirname(__file__), "parameters", <fileName>), "r") as file:
  json = json.load(file)
deployment = azureConnection.deployWithParameters(template, parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the default parameters provided in the template you don't need to pass a parameters file. For example, you could just deploy the Key Vault using this command:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyKeyVaultDeployment -ResourceGroupName MyRg -Mode Incremental -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/modules/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/1.0/azuredeploy.json
```

Since we do not specify a parameter file or pass parameters into the command, the deployment process will then simply use the default values from the template.

Comment: Hi @holger, I was trying with an empty parameters file, because no matter which parameter I specify, I always get the same error message Ex:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters":
  {
    "vaultName":
    {
      "value": "testkeyvault"
    }
  }
} The error message is still the same. Any ideas of what is wrong on the parameters file?

Comment: Hm. I tested it successfully. 
Created a file param.json, added content `{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaultName": { 
            "value": "testkeyvault29092022" 
        }
    }
}` then ran `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name md -ResourceGroupName myRg -Mode Incremental -TemplateUri 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/modules/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/1.0/azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile .\param.json`

Comment: Maybe it is an encoding issue with the json file? Is it saved as utf-8? (I'm guessing really)

Comment: yes, it is in UTF-8. I just tried with the same keyvault name that you provided in the exampel (just in case the name can cause conflict) and still got the same error

Comment: Strange. How are you deploying the template by the way? PowerShell, Azure CLI or Azure Portal?

Comment: I am trying with PowerShell (New-AzDeployment) and a python script. I will add the python code above as reference

Comment: Thanks. WIth PowerShell you would need to use `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` though. `New-AzDeployment` would not work as it would try to deploy against the subscription scope.

Comment: same error with New-AzResourceGroupDeployment. With python is also only working deployment without parameters

Comment: Is the syntax New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <my_resource_group> -TemplateFile "c:\Temp\Templates\keyvault.json" -TemplateParameterFile "c:\Temp\Parameters\params.json"? or I am missing something.

Comment: That's basically it. Only the Name for the deployment is missing. `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name SomeName -ResourceGroupName <my_resource_group> -TemplateFile "c:\Temp\Templates\keyvault.json" -TemplateParameterFile "c:\Temp\Parameters\params.json"`

Comment: :( same issue adding the name